# Yocto directdisk bootloader remove options

Tags: kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, boot, yocto-wic

I am updating our yocto based system from fido to morty. I am building VMware image and everything works fine, the system builds fine and boots succesfully.

The problem is that in now that I have updated the system (didn't happen in fido) I'm getting options to choose from when starting the virtual machine:

```
Select kernel options and boot kernel

Graphics console boot
Serial console boot

press [Tab] to edit, [Return] to select
```

if I choose to edit the options I can see that the options correspond to kernel options as follows:

```
Graphics console boot: /vmlinuz LABEL=boot root=/dev/sda2
Serial console boot: /vmlinuz LABEL=boot root=/dev/sda2 console=ttyS0,115200
```

If I don't choose anything it chooses Graphics console boot automatically, which is good since that's the one I want.

*BUT* I'd like to know how to override this and just immediately select the graphics console boot and start the boot.

I found that the options are defined in [/poky/tree/scripts/lib/wic/canned-wks/directdisk-bootloader-config.cfg](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/scripts/lib/wic/canned-wks/directdisk-bootloader-config.cfg?h=master)

I also noticed that the serial console is not defined in morty, which also confuses me, as I should not be seeing it since it's not in morty? But that's not the problem and I just want it to boot directly with the options `/vmlinuz LABEL=boot root=/dev/sda2`

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on https://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually found the answer on my own. All I had to do was add

```
AUTO_SYSLINUXMENU = "0"
```

in

```
/conf/<machine>.conf
```

The variable is defined in `/poky/meta/classes/syslinux.bbclass` and has a description

> ${AUTO_SYSLINUXMENU} - set this to 1 to enable creating an automatic
>   menu